# stateless function using es6 arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found below example odd.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem } from 'reactstrap';

const Example = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Breadcrumb tag="nav">
        <BreadcrumbItem tag="a" href="#">Home</BreadcrumbItem>
      </Breadcrumb>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Because I always do

```
function Example(){
   return ( <div>Stateless function</div> );
}

export default Example;
```

What is the point using arrow function in stateless component? If it's method, I know the benefit is you don't have to use bind(this), but I don't know why the author used arrow function in stateless component.

Comment: *"What is the point using arrow function in stateless component?"* There is absolutely no point in this case. The only reason why hipster developer use it is because it's popular and looks cool. Arrow functions is the way to provide lexical scope, not just to get rid of function keyword.

Comment: Was that one of several similar functions where the other functions did use `this` and/or the `props` argument? If so, the author may have just wanted all the functions to look the same. Your way looks like a syntax error to me though. Shouldn't it be `function` rather than `const`?

Comment: using `function` is better in this case because you can write `export default function Example() ...`: no need to declare first then export as default. With arrow function, you have to separate declaration from default export: so sad...

Comment: Don't forget that arrow functions allow an implicit return, so you don't actually have to `return` the JSX. e.g. `const Example = (props) => <div />` or `const Example = (props) => ( <div /> )`. At the end of the day use whatever you like best.